# Winform application doesn't run properly

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In my home and work pc's and in one friend of mine's it runs just ok, but when i sent it to someone else it 'loads' for 10 seconds responseless, then there is an error:

[alt text http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3045472/Sem%20t%C3%ADtulo-1.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3045472/Sem%20t%C3%ADtulo-1.png)

Since it works on at least four computers, i assume the program itself is just ok (same exact EXE).

What could be happening ?

info:

- C#
- .net 3.5
- worked on Windows 7 32/64 bits,
  windows XP and vista.
- does some threading simple stuff, but
  it doesn't even open the form, and it
  doesn't open up running either, so
  the functionality is irrelevant.

Comment: Can you check the event viewer on the machine where the program crashed and see if it provides any additional details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are infinitely many possible answers.  So I will give you the way to figure it out instead.

Add a handler for the event: [AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) of type [UnhandledExceptionEventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.unhandledexceptioneventhandler.aspx).

You will be able to see the reason for the crash.  It's probably best to write it out to a file somewhere anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The first check is to make sure the .NET framework is already installed on the target machine, then make use of Brian's suggestion (which will not even work if the framework is not installed!).